# Can I use same column twice with different filters in sql query?

Tags: sql

I am creating a report for a customer. In it I need to combine information from 4 tables. It's all fine until the last table, where I use just one column. This column contains phones and emails (all in one). I need to display email address and phone number in separate column, but they come from the same column.

I can display both but they show in separate rows. I can also duplicate the column and then sort it out in excel but customer needs to be able to do it themselves without editing it after.

```
    SELECT CustomerProcessO.GID,
           CustomerProcessO.FOIF,
           Customers.FirstName,
           Customers.LastName,
           SalesPersons.FirstName,
           SalesPersons.LastName,
           DynamicListData.DataContent AS Email,
           DynamicListData.DataContent AS Phone
      FROM CustomerProcessO
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers ON CustomerProcessO.id = Customers.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesPersons ON CustomerProcessO.GIDSalesPerson = SalesPersons.GID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DynamicListData ON ParentId = Customers.id
     WHERE DynamicListData.KeyField = 'EMAILS'
        OR DynamicListData.KeyField = 'PHONES'
```

The results I'm getting are correct but I get phone numbers and emails in two separate rows. I need to have one column with email and one column with phone number

Answer (score 2):

You can join the same table twice:

```
SELECT dld1.DataContent AS Email, dld2.DataContent AS Phone
...
LEFT JOIN DynamicListData dld1 ON dld1.ParentId = Customers.id AND dld1.KeyField = 'EMAILS'
LEFT JOIN DynamicListData dld2 ON dld2.ParentId = Customers.id AND dld2.KeyField = 'PHONES'
```

Comment: You should propose more meaningful table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        CustomerProcessO.GID, CustomerProcessO.FOIF, Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, SalesPersons.FirstName, SalesPersons.LastName, 
DLD1.Phone, DLD2.Email
FROM            CustomerProcessO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers ON CustomerProcessO.id = Customers.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesPersons ON CustomerProcessO.GIDSalesPerson = SalesPersons.GID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ParentId, KeyField, DataContent AS [Phone] FROM DynamicListDate) DLD1 ON DLD1.ParentId = Customers.id AND DLD1.KeyField = 'PHONES'
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ParentId, KeyField, DataContent AS [Email] FROM DynamicListDate) DLD2 ON DLD2.ParentId = Customers.id AND DLD2.KeyField = 'EMAILS'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't created the code. Thanks for your help this works great!